# SQLite3 query slow in Swift

Tags: sql, swift, sqlite

The following SQLite3 statement is very slow in my Swift-Code (see below)

Any idea why ??

Currently, it takes approx 30 seconds from breakpoint-1 to breakpoint-2

```
// .. breakpoint-1
while ((sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
   // .. breakpoint-2
}
```

My SQLite-db is 450 MB in size and the query is quite complex.
I am simply not sure if this "while-loop" cannot be made faster somehow ??

Here is the Query:

```
var query1: String = ""

query1 =
"""
SELECT DISTINCT st.departure_time as time, t.trip_headsign, r.route_desc, t.trip_id
FROM stops s
INNER JOIN calendar c ON t.service_id = c.service_id
INNER JOIN stop_times st  ON st.stop_id = s.stop_id
INNER JOIN trips t ON t.trip_id = st.trip_id
INNER JOIN routes r ON r.route_id = t.route_id
WHERE c.\(weekDay) = 1
AND st.departure_time > "\(departureTime)"
AND st.stop_id LIKE '\(stop_id)%'
AND s.stop_name <> t.trip_headsign
ORDER BY st.departure_time ASC
LIMIT 80
"""
```

Also, after [maddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)'s input, I did create a new DB - this time "indexed" (see on which columns below..) . After indexing - the size of the DB increased to double its original size.

**But with the above query and the newly indexed DB, the speed is unfortunately still identically slow (> 30 sec).
How would I need to change the query after having an "indexed" DB ???
How can I increase query-speed ???**

These are the indexed columns:

```
CREATE INDEX departure_time_IDX ON stop_times(departure_time);
CREATE INDEX stop_times_id_IDX ON stop_times(stop_id);
CREATE INDEX stop_times_trip_id_IDX ON stop_times(trip_id);
CREATE INDEX stop_name_IDX ON stops(stop_name);
CREATE INDEX stop_id_IDX ON stops(stop_id);
CREATE INDEX trip_headsign_IDX ON trips(trip_headsign);
CREATE INDEX trip_id_IDX ON trips(trip_id);
CREATE INDEX trip_route_id_IDX ON trips(route_id);
CREATE INDEX service_id_IDX ON trips(service_id);
CREATE INDEX route_desc_IDX ON routes(route_desc);
CREATE INDEX route_id_IDX ON routes(route_id);
CREATE INDEX cal_service_id_IDX ON calendar(service_id);
CREATE INDEX monday_IDX ON calendar(monday);
CREATE INDEX tuesday_IDX ON calendar(tuesday);
CREATE INDEX wednesday_IDX ON calendar(wednesday);
CREATE INDEX thursday_IDX ON calendar(thursday);
CREATE INDEX friday_IDX ON calendar(friday);
CREATE INDEX saturday_IDX ON calendar(saturday);
CREATE INDEX sunday_IDX ON calendar(sunday);
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`

[image]

I have the query down to 3 seconds if I eliminate the INNER JOIN's of `trips` and `routes`. Of course, I need those two for the result I expect out of this. But at least it shows that the INNER JOIN's of those two extra tables are slowing things down.

Also, it has to be noticed that `stop_times` is the biggest table of all !
(then comes `trips` - and the others are all smaller...)

The 3-sec query looks like this :

```
var faster_query: String = ""

faster_query =
"""
SELECT DISTINCT st.departure_time as time
FROM stops s
INNER JOIN stop_times st  ON st.stop_id = s.stop_id
WHERE st.departure_time > "19:51:00"
AND st.stop_id LIKE '8505000%'
ORDER BY st.departure_time ASC
LIMIT 80
"""
```

The EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for this `faster_query` looks like this:

[image]

Here is the whole code for the SQLite3 query

```
// Open SQLite database
var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
if let path = self.departure_filePath?.path {
    if sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

        var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        // Run SELECT query from db
        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query1, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {

            // Loop through all results from query1
            // .. breakpoint-1
            while ((sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                // .. breakpoint-2

                let ID = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
                if ID != nil {
                    IDString = String(cString:ID!)
                } else {
                    print("ID not found", terminator: "")
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's taking half a minute to get between the breakpoints it's definitely the query that's the problem. If you post the query someone should be able to help.

Comment: Run your query in the sqlite3 command line shell using `.explain on`. You are probably doing lots of full table scans. You may need to appropriate indexes to make your query work better.

Comment: How long does the query take if you run it with some SQL client?

Comment: On a side note, I hope you have actual code not shown in your question that properly finalizes the prepared statement and closes the database or you are going to have serious resource issues.

Comment: Good idea, a_horse_with_no_name_, Using a SQL-client - the query takes also quite long - it is not the Swift or OS then that is the issue. But the query ! And how could I improve it ?

Comment: Thanks - maddy - no I do not have more "finalizing code" yet. How would this look like ??

Comment: And also, maddy, do you have an example of how to "appropriately index" the tables to make the query work better ???

Comment: I did create a new DB - this time "indexed" (on all of the columns used in the INNER JOIN, AND and in the WHERE query) . The size of the DB increased to double its original size. But with the above query, the speed is unfortunately still identically slow. How would I need to change the query after having a "indexed" DB ???

Comment: see updated Question above....

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: I added the query plan in my question above...

Comment: Debugging 101. Reduce the query to a simple SELECT over a single table. Start with `stop_times`, because it has the most WHERE conditions. Is it slow? If no, add a join. Wash, rinse, repeat until you found out at which point the query becomes slow.

Comment: Thing is - I cannot really ommit anything in the query since all seems necessary for the correct result. However, I am looking for things to re-arrange or adapt the query in such a way that results remain the same (if at all possible altering the query)...?

Comment: The correct result is irrelevant at this point. You want to find out *at which point* the query gets slow, exactly.

Comment: @Tomalak: I eliminated two INNER JOINS (of tables `trips` and `routes`) - now it is down to 3 sec query - see in question above - I also added the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for this `faster_query` as well in my original question.... - any idea now on how to change the original query ??

Comment: Now add a single index that includes three fields on `stop_times`, over `(departure_time ASC, stop_id ASC, trip_id ASC)`. This should help speeding up this JOIN. After that, add the `trips` JOIN and the according columns and WHERE clauses. Still fast?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170240/discussion-between-tomalak-and-ikk).